# Reporting Application Errors by Email

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Recently I was reading about the log4j appender. I found out that you can use the either `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` to create the `SMTPAppender` to set up the email configuration. I currently have a Java application, and I want to send an email notification when an error occurs. I found many xml example on google, but I cannot find any example in `properties file`. I am wondering is there a good way or some tutorial website on teaching how to set up this email configuration using the `**.properties**` instead of xml?

Help will be appreciated. An example or a website link for reference will be helpful? Thanks

This is one of the ([website](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/29/smtp-logging.html?page=1)) I found, but they use xml

Answer (score 0):

> `Log4j.properties(PropertyConfigurator)` are legacy thing and I would
>   recommend you to upgrade to use `log4j.xml (DomConfigurator)` since
>   you are `Log4j2`. Some of the advance features are not supported using
>   the `PropertyConfigurator`

However, you can define smtp setting in your `log4j.properties` like this:

```
#email appender
log4j.appender.mail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.mail.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=smtp.serverhere.com
log4j.appender.mail.From=someone@serverhere.com
log4j.appender.mail.To=whoknows@serverhere.com
log4j.appender.mail.Subject=unknown subject
log4j.appender.mail.threshold=error
log4j.appender.mail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n
```

You can refer to this link for all the smtp properties: [SmtpAppenderProperties.html](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.SmtpAppenderProperties.html)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick respond. I am just wondering is this the same as when I am using log4j2 instead? If I use log4j2, will the syntax be the same?
and after this, do I need to install the properties into my application using the `getProperty` method in order to make this work? 

`private static String SMTPHost;
SMTPHost = props.getProperty("P8Url");`

Comment: @Amazed properties(propertyconfigurator) are legacy thing and I would recommend you to use xml (domconfigurator) since you are log4j2. Some of the things are not supported using the propertyconfigurator.